# Toggle function not working in Processing (ControlP5)

Tags: image, processing, generator

I just made my image generator work with PNG files. For now, it's divided into 3 categories (backgrounds, objects & texts). These are now all combined, and with every mouse click it randomises these PNGs.

I made three toggles, where you could to choose to show either the background and the objects on top, all of them, or all separate. Whenever I run the sketch, it shows the "grey" background, but when I use the toggles, it doesn't show anything, or shows a flickering image, where the mouse-click can't be used to go to the next image. I can't seem to find the problem. Hopefully, you can help. :)

```java
import controlP5.*;

boolean showBackground = false;
boolean showObjects = false;
boolean showGrids = false;

ControlP5 cp5;

PImage[] myImageArray = new PImage[8];
PImage[] myImageArray2 = new PImage[15];
PImage[] myImageArray3 = new PImage[15];



void setup() {
  size(1436, 847);
  background(211, 211, 211);

  for (int i=0; i<myImageArray.length; i++) {
    myImageArray[i] = loadImage  ( "o" + i + ".png");
    myImageArray2[i] = loadImage  ( "g" + i + ".png");
    myImageArray3[i] = loadImage( "b" + i + ".jpg");
    cp5 = new ControlP5(this);

    // create a toggle and change the default look to a (on/off) switch look
    cp5.addToggle("showBackground")
      .setPosition(40, 250)
      .setSize(50, 20)
      .setValue(true)
      .setMode(ControlP5.SWITCH);

    cp5.addToggle("showObjects")
      .setPosition(40, 400)
      .setSize(50, 20)
      .setValue(true)
      .setMode(ControlP5.SWITCH);


    cp5.addToggle("showGrid")
      .setPosition(40, 600)
      .setSize(50, 20)
      .setValue(true)
      .setMode(ControlP5.SWITCH);
  }
  display();
}
void display() {

  image(myImageArray3[(int)random(myImageArray.length)], 0, 0, 1436, 847); // b

  image(myImageArray2[(int)random(myImageArray.length)], 0, 0, 1436, 847); // g

  image(myImageArray[(int)random(myImageArray.length)], 0, 0, 1436, 847); // o
}
void mousePressed() {
  display();
}

void draw() {
  pushMatrix();

  if (showBackground==false) {
    image(myImageArray3[(int)random(myImageArray.length)], 0, 0, 1436, 847); // b
  } else {
    background(211, 211, 211);
  }
  if (showGrids==false) {
    image(myImageArray2[(int)random(myImageArray.length)], 0, 0, 1436, 847); // g
  } else {
    background(211, 211, 211);
  }
  if (showObjects==false) {
    image(myImageArray[(int)random(myImageArray.length)], 0, 0, 1436, 847); // o
  } else {
    background(211, 211, 211);
  }

  popMatrix();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of things where the logic your wrote in your code might not match what you had in mind:

1. When you call display() on mouse it renders those 3 images **once** (also it will be different images within those since it's using a randomised index). Similarly in draw(), when an does get picked to be rendered, frames will be flickering fast as a random index is generated multiple times per second(each frame). You may want to randomise indices in a different event (e.g. mouse or key press) and store this value in a variable you can re-use.
2. the conditions you use in draw(): you probably meant to check if the values are `true`(toggled enabled/turned on in controlP5) ? (e.g. e.g. `if (showBackground==true)` and initialise the toggles with `false`, instead of true?)
3. a big one: in `draw()` , after each condition(`showBackground,showGrids,showObjects`), if it's false, you're clearing the the whole frame (so a previous image would be erased)
4. you have 3 arrays, but you use the size of the first(`myImageArray.length`) only, which means, even though you may have more images for `myImageArray2` and `myImageArray3`, you're not loading, nor displaying them.
5. The third grid is labeled "showGrid" when it should be "showGrids": if you aren't consistent with the toggle labels and variable names, toggles won't update the variable names.
6. you should use more descriptive names for the arrays: it will make it easier to scan/follow your code on the long run.
7. there's no need to add toggles multiple times in the for loop where you load images: once will do.

Here's what I mean:

```
import controlP5.*;

boolean showBackground = false;
boolean showObjects = false;
boolean showGrids = false;

ControlP5 cp5;

PImage[] objects = new PImage[8];
PImage[] grids = new PImage[15];
PImage[] backgrounds = new PImage[15];

int currentImage = 0;

void setup() {
  size(1436, 847);
  //load objects
  for (int i=0; i<objects.length; i++) {
    objects[i] = loadImage  ( "o" + i + ".png");
  }
  //load grids
  for(int i = 0 ; i < grids.length; i++){
    grids[i] = loadImage  ( "g" + i + ".png");
  }
  //load backgrounds
  for(int i = 0 ; i < grids.length; i++){
    backgrounds[i] = loadImage( "b" + i + ".jpg");
  }
  //setup UI
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
  // create a toggle and change the default look to a (on/off) switch look
  cp5.addToggle("showBackground")
    .setPosition(40, 250)
    .setSize(50, 20)
    .setValue(false)
    .setMode(ControlP5.SWITCH);

  cp5.addToggle("showObjects")
    .setPosition(40, 400)
    .setSize(50, 20)
    .setValue(false)
    .setMode(ControlP5.SWITCH);


  cp5.addToggle("showGrids")
    .setPosition(40, 600)
    .setSize(50, 20)
    .setValue(false)
    .setMode(ControlP5.SWITCH);
}
void mousePressed() {
  //go to next image index
  currentImage = currentImage + 1;
  //check if the incremented index is still valid, otherwise, reset it to 0 (so it doesn't go out of bounds)
  if (currentImage >= objects.length) {
    currentImage = 0;
  }
}

void draw() {
  //clear current frame
  background(211);//for gray scale value you can just use one value: the brightness level :)

  if (showBackground==true) {
    image(backgrounds[currentImage], 0, 0, 1436, 847); // b
  } 
  if (showGrids==true) {
    image(grids[currentImage], 0, 0, 1436, 847); // g
  } 
  if (showObjects==true) {
    image(objects[currentImage], 0, 0, 1436, 847); // o
  }
}
```

Note that currently the same index is used for all 3 arrays.
You may want to add a separate index variable for each array (e.g. `currentObjectIndex, currentBackgroundIndex, currentGridIndex`) that you can increment independently of each other.

I recommend having a bit more patience and double checking your code first.
Visualise what each line of code will do, then check if it actually does what you expect it to do. Either you will learn something new or improve your logic.

Also, if mentally joggling 3 arrays is tricky (and it can be), go one step back: try your logic with one array only until you get the hang of it, then move on.
A step backwards is sometimes a step forward when you're going in the wrong direction.

As creative as you'd like to be with Processing, bare in mind, the interface to plugging your ideas to it is still a series of one instruction at a time, each precisely tuned to do exactly what you want it to do. There's room for fun, but unfortunately you need to get past the boring parts first

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, I just have a question about the code so I fully understand, here it loads the objects, but what does the first sentence exactly say and refer to for (int i=0; i<objects.length; i++) ? And where do I place the random, so the image goes from b1.jpg for example to b20.jpg instead of 1,2,3,4

Comment: Feel free to vote and/or mark the answer as a solution if it solved the issue. Regarding random, try changing the value of ```currentImage``` to use ```random()```, but be aware of array lengths so you don't go out of bounds :)